# How to implement routing so that when you click on a link, it doesn't open a new tab in your browser?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

The issue is quite simple. I have a 'Home' caption created which should, when clicked on, just take you to the default page path in the browser. For example, I am on the path /dashboard, I click on the subtitle home and it should take me to the address /home so it happens, but a new browser tab is opened each time, I would like to make this transfer take place only in one browser tab. How could I do this?

**routing**:

```
  {path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent},
```

**component:**

```
  <div><a href="#" target="_blank" class="positronx" routerLink="homepage" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></div>
```

Comment: Hi, try to remove href and target from a tag

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you added `target="_blank"` to your a-Tag.

Description of `target="_blank"` from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp).

> Opens the linked document in a new window or tab

Also, when you use `routerLink` you don't have to use the `href` property because you already show to another path with the Angular directive `routerLink`.

In the end, your code should look like this:

```
 <div><a class="positronx" routerLink="homepage" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `target="_blank"` from `a` tag.